# scrollIntoView with smooth behavior can be stopped by clicking

Tags: javascript, mobile, touch, smooth-scrolling, js-scrollintoview

I have a container with 100% height and overflow-hidden, which should only be scrolled clicking a button that triggers the `scrollIntoView` function for the container's children.

On desktops this works flawless, but on mobile, the `scrollIntoView` function can be stopped by random clicking/scrolling around on the page. How can I prevent this?

I tried to prevent the `touchmove` event (using `e.preventDefault(); e.stopPropagation();`), but it did not help.

Comment: Are you sure that you want to stop it? It will be very annoying

Comment: @KonradLinkowski Yes. Stopping the scrolling event leaves my application in an unrecoverable mode where it transits between two views. Trust me, it makes perfect sense to do this for my objective.

Comment: Example of what happens: https://i.ibb.co/dk4rR3P/example.gif